# Csv to Json with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, json, csv

I would like to convert a csv file to json with the csv-parser library.

That's my file csv :

```
account/firstname,account/lastname,account/location/countryName,account/location/town,account/location/address,Id
Babouche,Dorian,US,Washington,***,1
```

That's the code i have for the csv to json :

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
let results = [];
let data;
fs.createReadStream('simple.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
    .on('end', () => {
        data = JSON.stringify(results, null, 2)

        fs.writeFile('user.json', data, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log("JSON data is saved.");
        });
})
```

Desired JSON:

```
[{
    account: {
        firstname: "Babouche",
        lastname: "Dorian",
        location: {
            countryName: "US",
            town: "Washington",
            address: "***"
        } 
    },
    Id: "1",
}
]
```

The result i have:

```
[
  {
    "account/firstname": "Babouche",
    "account/lastname": "Dorian",
    "account/location/countryName": "US",
    "account/location/town": "Washington",
    "account/location/address": "***",
    "Id": " 1"
  }
]
```

I would like a recommendation on how to easily accomplish this, please.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using '*json-2-csv*'

First, install the package

```
npm install json-2-csv
```

Import:

```
let converter = require('json-2-csv');
```

Function with Callback

```
let csv2jsonCallback = function (err, json) {
    if (err) throw err;
        console.log(typeof json);
        console.log(json.length);
        console.log(json);
}

converter.csv2json(csv, csv2jsonCallback);
```

Function with Promise

```
converter.csv2jsonAsync(csv)
.then(console.log)
.catch((err) => console.log('ERROR: ' + err.message));
```